# Navigating back with back button is making lose BLoC state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation, gorouter

Going back to previous screen by using back button is making lose BLOC State. Flutter

I'm currently using `flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3` and `go_router: ^7.1.1`. I have two screens, one is
`display items screen`  and another one is `add items screen`. In display items screen i'm using `initState()` to load the items data with the help of bloc and it is working fine. But when i navigate to add items screen and click on back button, the display items screen is showing white screen but it was suppose to show the data. Here is my code.

display_items_Screen.dart

```
class DisplayItemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DisplayItemsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DisplayItemsScreen> createState() => _DisplayItemsScreenState();
}

class _DisplayItemsScreenState extends State<DisplayItemsScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<DisplayItemsBloc>().add(DisplayItemsLoadEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context
            .push("/add-items")
            ,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Display Items"),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<DisplayItemsBloc, DisplayItemsState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is DisplayItemsErrorState) {
            showSnackBar("Something went wrong! please try again.");
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is DisplayItemsLoadingState) {
            return const LoadingView();
          } else if (state is DisplayItemsLoadedState) {
            final categories = state.userProductCategories;
            return DisplayItem(categories: categories); // stateless widget GridView.builder()
          } else {  // it is running this else condition when navigated using back button
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

add_items_screen.dart

```
class AddItemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddItemsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddItemsScreen> createState() => _AddItemsScreenState();
}

class _AddItemsScreenState extends State<AddItemsScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AddItemsBloc>().add(AddItemsLoadEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Add Items"),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<AddItemsBloc, AddItemsState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AddItemsErrorState) {
            showSnackBar("Something went wrong! please try again.");
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AddItemsLoadingState) {
            return const LoadingView();
          } else if (state is AddItemsLoadedState) {
            final items = state.loadedItems;
            return AddItem(categories: items);
          } else {
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

router.dart

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class AppRoutes {
  static routes() {
    return GoRouter(
      initialLocation: "/",
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
            path: "/display-items",
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext _, GoRouterState state) {
              return CupertinoPage(
                child: const DisplayItemsScreen(),
                key: state.pageKey,
                restorationId: state.pageKey.value,
              );
            },
           ),
        GoRoute(
            path: "/add-items",
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext _, GoRouterState state) {
              return CupertinoPage(
                child: const AddItemsScreen(),
                key: state.pageKey,
                restorationId: state.pageKey.value,
               );
            },
           )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

bloc_providers.dart

```
class BlocProviders {
  final DisplayItemsRepository _displayItemsRepository = DisplayItemsRepository();
  final AddItemsRepository _addItemsRepository =
      AddItemsRepository();

  blocs() {
    return [
      BlocProvider<DisplayItemsBloc>(
        create: (context) => DisplayItemsBloc(repository: _displayItemsRepository),
      ),
      BlocProvider<AddItemsBloc>(
        create: (context) => AddItemsBloc(repository: _addItemsRepository),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  final BlocProviders blocProviders = BlocProviders();
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: blocProviders.blocs(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  final _router = AppRoutes.routes();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: snackbarKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      routerConfig: _router,
      // routeInformationParser: AppRoutes.routes().routeInformationParser,
      // routeInformationProvider: AppRoutes.routes().routeInformationProvider,
      // routerDelegate: AppRoutes.routes().routerDelegate,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe In your `DisplayItemsBloc` code some state is triggering.
If you provide your bloc code it would be good to understand.

But you can use buildWhen function in your BlocConsumer to stop building unnecessary states:

```
buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
              current is DisplayItemsLoadingState || current is DisplayItemsLoadedState
```

and you can make your builder function like this:

```
builder: (context, state) {
       if (state is DisplayItemsLoadedState) {
        final categories = state.userProductCategories;
        return DisplayItem(categories: categories); 
      } else { 
        return const LoadingView();
      }
    },
```

Comment: The else condition is getting executed inside the builder of BlocConsumer in display_items_Screen.dart. it means no bloc state is getting triggered when we navigate back to display_items_Screen using back button because i'm calling the load event inside initState and the initState only runs one time in display_items_Screen. Is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: The above solution which you have suggested with buildWhen is working, but if i select any new item in add item screen and comeback to display items screen that new item which i have added from add item screen is not getting updated in display item screen and also  the api is also not getting called again in display item screen after coming back  from add item screen to get the updated data

Comment: @BhuvanaChandra on your first question, the builder function runs only when build function calls or Bloc state change, even if you try to rebuild the screen intentionally by calling setState or any other way BLOC does have previous and current state data, here both if and else if conditions are not matching with the current state so it is going to the else condition, that means somehow it triggers some other state. you can print the state.runtimetype in the builder function to get know which state are triggering

Comment: @BhuvanaChandra on your second question whenever you add an item try to emit DisplayItemsLoadedState with different data (if you are using Equatable), so it will trigger the builder function in the display screen. And when you are calling 
the API to get updated data on the display screen. Require proper data related to that. so can provide the solution for that.

Comment: @BhuvanaChandra one more thing to add. Even DisplayItemsErrorState can run the builder function and it will break your functionality.